# Why does F# constrain my code and remove generics?

Tags: f#

```
type VBO<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType> = 
    { Handle : int
      target : BufferTarget
      size : int
      dataSize : int
      data : 'T []
      pos : int
      usage : BufferUsageHint }

type VBO = 
    static member Create(target, size, pos, usage, (data : Vector3 [])) = 
        VBO.CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, Vector2.SizeInBytes, data)

    // Type mismatch. Expecting Vector3 but found Vector2
    static member Create(target, size, pos, usage, (data : Vector2 [])) = 
        VBO.CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, Vector2.SizeInBytes, data)

    // This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations.
    // The type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'Vector3'.
    static member CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, dataSize, (data : 'T [])) = 
        let h = GL.GenBuffer()
        { Handle = h
          target = target
          size = size
          dataSize = dataSize
          data = data
          pos = pos
          usage = usage }
```

F# tries to constrain my code but I want it to be generic. I don't really care about what type the data is I just need it pass in the correct dataSize.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The F# compiler seems to specialise generic types if they are used at a particular instantiation in the same block of code. Try splitting up your declaration like this:

```
type VBO<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType> = 
    { Handle : int
      target : BufferTarget
      size : int
      dataSize : int
      data : 'T []
      pos : int
      usage : BufferUsageHint }

type VBO = 
    static member CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, dataSize, (data : 'T [])) = 
        let h = GL.GenBuffer()
        { Handle = h
          target = target
          size = size
          dataSize = dataSize
          data = data
          pos = pos
          usage = usage }

type VBO with
    static member Create(target, size, pos, usage, (data : Vector3 [])) = 
        VBO.CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, Vector2.SizeInBytes, data)

    static member Create(target, size, pos, usage, (data : Vector2 [])) = 
        VBO.CreateImpl(target, size, pos, usage, Vector2.SizeInBytes, data)
```

Answer (score 3):

F#'s type inference works top-to-bottom and left-to-right, which occasionally leads to interesting corner cases.  In particular, reordering method definitions within a type can affect the inferred types.  As Ganesh has pointed out, one solution to your problem is to break your type  up into disjoint chunks, but this isn't actually necessary - just putting the generic method first should be sufficient (and note that you can also drop the type annotation on `data`, if desired).

You can see very similar behavior with simple `let rec` bindings.  Consider:

```
let rec f() = h 5
and g() = h "test"
and h x = x
```

When attempting to infer the type of `f`, the compiler notes that `h` must take an `int` as input, which makes `g`'s definition invalid.  Reordering the definitions to put `h` first is the easiest solution (then the compiler can infer a generic type for `h` before looking at the bodies of `f` and `g`, so everything goes through fine).

Alternatively, you can explicitly make `h` generic and add type annotations to help the compiler out:

```
let rec f() = h 5
and g() = h "test"
and h<'t> (x:'t) :'t = x
```

This can be inconvenient since it can require a significant annotation overhead, but there are circumstances where simply reordering definitions is insufficient to allow the compiler to infer the correct types, so it may sometimes be necessary.

Comment: I didn't try this specific code as I didn't have all the types available, but I'm fairly sure I've encountered cases where neither explicit type parameters nor reordering was enough to stop the compiler specialising generic types - whereas just inserting `type Foo with` into the middle of an existing definition of `Foo` did fix  it. I'll see if I can find one.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to look at the code to understand what went wrong.

So here is a simpler example that shows the same problem.

```
type test = 
    static member test (data:int) = test.actual(data)
    static member test (data:float) =test.actual(data)
    static member actual (data:'t) = ()
```

the problem is that for static member functions, all the types need to be known - or you need a generic type.

I think the simplest solution is to change your code to look like

```
let actual (data:'t) = ()

type test = 
    static member test (data:int) = actual(data)
    static member test (data:float) =actual(data)
```

Here, the compiler has much more freedom to alter the let binding to make it generic.

Comment: The code in the question does have a generic type argument, and the types are known, it's just that the F# compiler inappropriately specialises it. I don't think putting a type parameter on the `test` type makes sense, because the containing type itself isn't logically generic.